# paid membership pro memberlist-csv.php

Tags: php, wordpress, export-to-csv

I am currently using paid membership pro as a plugin for my WordPress site. I have added in new fields by going into the functions.php file in the file manager. The new fields have successfully shown on the registration page and the user profile page. I am trying to have these new fields appear in the "memberlist.csv" file when exported. On this page : https://www.paidmembershipspro.com/exporting-members-list-default-data-adding-new-columns/ it shows that I need to add "memberslist.csv => true" to the added field. This is what I added in the functions.php file:

```
//define the fields
$fields = array(); $tshirt = new PMProRH_Field("tshirt", "select", array( 'label' => 'T-shirt Size: ', 'options' => array('xsmall' => 'XSmall', 'small' => 'Small', 'medium' => 'Medium', 'large' => 'Large', 'xlarge' => 'XLarge', 'xxlarge' => 'XXLarge'), 'class' => 'tshirt', 'profile' => true, 'required' => 'true', 'memberslistcsv' => 'true' ));pmprorh_add_registration_field("after_password", $tshirt);
```

This did not affect the csv file. Is there any other way to add these new fields to the memberlist csv?

Comment: So you have followed the wrong recipe for how to add the info? It says on the link you provided, that the `memberslist.csv=>true` bit only applies to content added via the Register Helper AddOn - did you do that? If not, you need to read the next paragraph on the same page.

Comment: I did use the Register Helper AddOn to add the extra fields and to add memberslist.csv => true .  It still did not affect the php file. I cannot view the code recipe in the next paragraph because I do not have a PmPro Core Account.

Comment: However that did not stop me from trying the option in the second paragraph. I added some columns to the memberlist-csv.php, but the data that I put into the new registration fields do not show up in the exported csv. this is the code I added to the memberlist-csv.php file:

Comment: //any extra columns
 $extra_columns = apply_filters("pmpro_members_list_csv_extra_columns", $extra_columns);
 
 
 $extra_columns= array(
  array("theuser", "RaceType"),
  array("theuser", "Age"), 
  array("theuser", "donate"),
  array("theuser", "tshirt")

  );
 if(!empty($extra_columns))
 {
  foreach($extra_columns as $heading => $callback)
  {
   $csv_file_header .= "," . $heading;
  }
 }

 $csv_file_header = apply_filters("pmpro_members_list_csv_heading", $csv_file_header);
 $csv_file_header .='racetype,age,donateitem,tshirt';

Comment: You need to get the developer to add this, otherwise when you update the plugin any modifications you make to it will be erased.

Comment: @NathanielFlick what developer?

Comment: Sorry I mean the plugin developer, they need to add this as a feature or else you can't ever update the plugin.